# htaccess - how to not redirect based on url pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# load index.php by default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteBase /

# for all other requests load room.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php?u=$1 [L,NC]
```

My htaccess currently will redirect anyone to `room.php` if the url contains anything else but the root directory such as `http://www.example.com/anythingelse` if not it will simple direct to `index.php`

But I need to be able to not include this redirect for particular patters so I can create content in particular folders. For instance

```
http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/2
http://www.example.com/3
http://www.example.com/4
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these exclusions in your regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# load index.php by default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteBase /

# for all other requests load room.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(1|2|3|4)
RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php?u=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is `http://www.example.com/1` still going to `http://www.example.com/room.php?u=1`?

Comment: ok you have to be specific and provide details. What URL is not working?

Comment: No don't want your actual URL. Just replace your actual domain name with `example.com` and provide rest of the URL.

Comment: I didnt realize my index file was html and not php. Once I changed it, it worked :) thanks again man you are the best